# bootstrap carousel images coming one below another

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

i m trying to display all the featured images in a posttype as a carousel but currently all images come one below another instead of as a slides.plus i get numbers like "1.","2." and "3." above the images.

below is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 1000  
    })
});
</script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-9">


                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" >
                <!-Indicators->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li class="" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" ></li>
                    <li class="active" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
                    <li class="" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
                </ol>
                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <?php $arg= get_posts(array('post_type' => 'featured', 'numberposts' => -1));                               

                            foreach ( $arg as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
                            if (!empty($post))
                                    {                
                    ?>                  

                            <div class="item active"><a href="<?php echo get_field('link');?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>

                        <?php }  endforeach; ?>

                    </div>
                </div>

 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>             

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 1000  
    })
});
</script>

<script>$(document).ready(function(){$(".carousel-inner div:first").addClass("active"); });</script>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-9">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" >
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li class="" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" ></li>
            <li class="active" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
            <li class="" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <?php $arg= get_posts(array('post_type' => 'featured', 'numberposts' => -1));                               
                foreach ( $arg as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
                            if (!empty($post)) {                
            ?>                  
                <div class="item"><a href="<?php echo get_field('link');?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a></div>
            <?php }  endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>             
</div>
```

Add active class on runtime with JS Or jQuery and also add active class on only first div of image with php.
    active class mean all are active if all image are active all images show one below another.

Hope this helps. If you have a question, or if you don't understand something, feel free to ask.